# why my toolbar is not pinned to top

Tags: android

I've implemented simple Toolbar instead of the existing ActionBar and use it like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

However, when it's open in activity it's not pinned to the top:

[image]

Why?

**UPDATE:**
Here is my styles and implementation:

custom_toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarker</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<color name="primary">#457C50</color>
<color name="primaryDarker">#580C0C</color>
```

**Update 2:**

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/textLoadingProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/articlesList"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />
```

Comment: Please share `toolbar` in your `xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your activity layout has 16dp padding around it, just remove that padding and it will be fine.

Edit: Your xml layout should be like this

```
<include         
android:id="@+id/toolbar" 
layout="@layout/custom_toolbar" />

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/textLoadingProgressBar"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:visibility="gone" />

<ListView
android:id="@+id/articlesList"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. But now I have another problem, toolbar hides content. How can I make it behave like actionBar in that it doesn't overflow?

Comment: Toolbar View is just like any other View in Android.

Comment: So if you're using RelativeLayout, use layout_below="@id/toolbar" for the View below it